# centering divs on the same line

Tags: html, css, centering

I'm trying to center these 3 floated divs on the same line.  Here is a link to jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/dtps4fw8/2/

any suggestions?

HTML:

```
<div class="content">

    <div class="box">

    </div>
    <div class="box">

    </div>
    <div class="box">

    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
width: 30%;
height: 200px;
float: left;
background: gray;
border: black solid 2px;
box-sizing: border;
margin: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Why would you think anything in the code you have would center them?

Comment: Because I'm a dumbass who is new to this and I'm learning from free online resources

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dtps4fw8/3/)

To make the 3 `div`s centered, first of all, remove the `float`property and then to apply the floated effect, use `display:inline-block`. `inline-block` display gives a textual characteristics to the `div`. A `text-align:center` for the parent div would center these `inline-block` elements inside the parent.

Update your CSS as follows

```
.box {
  width: 30%;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: gray;
  border: black solid 2px;
  box-sizing: border;
  margin: 5px;
}

.content {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: @rodwater Glad that it helped you.. :)

Comment: Lol... @Lal. Your answer is great also, its more elaborate than mine. But it depends on how he sees them

Answer (score 1):

First the `float:left;` is not relevant in your case, just like Lal said, instead of `float:left;` its should be `display:inline-block;` and you can also add a relative positioning `position:relative;`

Answer (score 0):

I use flexbox. Very minimal and responsive.

```
.content {
  width:100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  flex-wrap:wrap;}

.box {
  height: 200px;
  flex:1;
  background: gray;
  border: black solid 2px;
  box-sizing: border;
  margin: 5px;}
```